# Set and sync time using ADB shell with Python

Tags: adb

I'm trying to sync up clocks exactly using adb shell commands with Python.

I can set the date/time using:

```
adb shell date 071710102020
```

This only changes the time up to the second.  Is there a way to set time up to the millisecond using adb shell on a Samsung device?

Another option is to change `$EPOCHREALTIME` up to the millisecond?  Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: I want to set this using python and adb.

Comment: I meant to say, is this specific to Python? It seems like the fact that you're using Python is incidental to the problem.

Comment: No it's not specific to Python.  I should have just put adb for the tag.  I do want to sync up pythons date/time to my samsung device as close as I can get it (up to the ms).

Comment: OK, I removed the [tag:python] tag then

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward solution is to sync *both*, the Android device and the machine running python using [ntp](http://www.ntp.org/). This is built in to Android and all modern operating systems including Windows, Linux and MacOS.

If you really want to sync the device to the host time, you first need to install and configure ntp on your machine and then you should be able to sync with adb shell like so

```sh
adb shell ntpdate -q <yourservername>
```